# How to pause the process in case of setBounds

Tags: java, multithreading, sleep, setbounds

I want to show movement of label for a while on pressing of button. Please help. 
Just tell me how I pause the process for a while during the changing of setBounds, in this case sleep method pauses the process but just last setBound statement executes only:

```
void ActionPerformed(..){
    Thread b = new Thread();

        try{
            label.setBounds(100,150,70,70);

            b.sleep(1000);
            label.setBounds(100,200,70,70);

            b.sleep(1000);
            label.setBounds(100,150,70,70);

        }catch(InterruptedException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to [SO]. You have not said what language or system you are using.

Comment: using java , i want to pause in changing of setBounds

Answer (score 1):

Read the [swing concurrency tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/index.html). Rule of thumbs:

- you may not sleep in the event dispatch thread, because it freezes the UI
- you may not access swing components in a thread other than the event dispatch thread

So, you need a separate thread that sleeps, and then asks the EDT to modify the bounds of the label.

Use a swing Timer, or call `SwingUtilities.invokeLater()` from your background thread so that the task of modifying the bounds of the label is done by the EDT.

Also, note that `sleep()` is a static method. It should be called using `Thread.sleep()`, not `b.sleep()`.